# css: how to "center" a big image inside limited width and height without changing dimensions

Tags: html, image, css

before anything: No I don't mean centering an image inside a div

**WHAT I WANT TO DO IS SIMILAR TO THE DESKTOP 'CENTER' OPTION HENCE THE TITLE PLEASE DON'T BE CONFUSED I JUST DON'T KNOW THE SUITABLE TERM OF WHAT I WANT**

I am making a certian css template for my use, but I have this question that I couldn't figure out ..

basically, there is an image before each post, so the width is known. I set it to 100% of a container called "post". post has a width of 75% of the browser

```
<div class="post">
  <h1>post title</h1>
  <img class="post-img" src="myImg.png" />
  <!--other elements-->
</div>
```

css:

```
.post {
  width: 75%;
.post-img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Now to the problem ..
although the width now is fixed regardless of the image, the height is pretty much automatic

I want to set the height to a certain value, like `max-height: 500px;` for example .. so when a picture is big:

1. make width = 100% of the post div
2. is the height > 500px? no then make it auto. yes then crop the extra part

an image[image]

as you can see, the black stroke is the limited width and height

the width was checked first so no extra parts to the left and right

the height is more than 500px, so it will be cropped and the viewed image would be the one inside the black frame

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` on the parents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i said `overflow:hidden;` is the one you need

```css
.container{
width: 700px;
}

.post {
width: 75%;
overflow:hidden;
border:2px solid #f63;
}

.post img{
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="post">
  <h1>post title</h1>
  <img class="post-img" src="http://www.petsworld.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/adorable-cat.jpg" />
  <!--other elements-->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, yes it is. If the parents have fixed size, then you give it overflow hidden to hide any content that breaking the size of the parents. with the image set to max-width:100%; then the size automatically implement the parents fixed size

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve may be something like that, using `background` instead of `<img>`, so you have a much more simple control on the image :

```css
.post {
  width: 75%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hasselblad-masters/web-hi-res-content/X1D-Sample-Images/X1D5_B0001993.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <h1>post title</h1>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <article>
    <p>Other content</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to wrap your image in a container and set the maximum sizes and overflow:hidden; on that container

Something like:

```
<div class="post">
    <h1>post title</h1>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="post-img" src="img.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .post {
        width: 75%;
    }

   .img-container {
       max-width: 100%;
       max-height: 100px;
       overflow: hidden;
   }
</style>
```